# Are golf courses biased towards left/right-handed players because of the way they can slice?

Tags: golf

If I'm not mistaken, right handed golfers can slice/bend the ball towards the right, and the opposite for left handed golfers. But doesn't that literally make some courses favor certain handedness over others? If a course has more holes that bend towards the right, then right-handers have a huge advantage, right? Or am I underestimating golfers' ability to bend the ball in both directions? Or do courses evenly split between left and right-bending courses?

The reason I ask is because this seems like a blatant disadvantage, as compared to other sports. E.g. in boxing and tennis, theoretically, a right-hander has to deal with a left-hander just as much the left-hander has to deal with the right-hander. It's completely symmetric (in theory).

And as a simple follow-up, which handedness does the Masters Augusta course favor?

Comment: Perhaps worth noting this kind of asymmetry isn't unique to golf: for example, Yankee Stadium has a "short porch" (shorter distance to the wall) in right field, thus favouring left-handed hitters.